# How I can read optical encoder pulses on High RPM

Tags: microcontroller, dc-motor, pulse, encoder, brushed-dc-motor

I am working on a project in which I am using two DC motors with encoder but after certain speed ( my DC motor operating voltage is 24 V but when I give it more than 15V )my MCU CC1350  start missing encoder pulses. I don’t want replace my MCU for now is their any alternative to read the pulses A , B with accuracy
I am using interrupt (Rising)
[MCU Cc1350](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc1350.pdf?ts=1620973826253&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.co.in%252F)
[Encoder datasheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1flir0JlN4crW3pjLkWCFSug23ULJu_Ln/view?usp=sharing)
[Motor datasheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13HK7fAnAver1qq9xdjFVWvaKzqo_1RAk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Without any indication of the actual RPM, the resolution of the encoder and the clock frequency of your controller, it is very hard to give an useful advice.

Comment: How are you reading the pulses? Polling? HW-Interrupt? Dedicated Pulse counter input?

Comment: Are you using a hardware interrupt or software polling? Are you using some sort of library, subroutine, or real-time operating system to schedule tasks?

Comment: @SystemTheory I am using interrupt (Rising)

Comment: Are your motors using the same power source as the MCU? Motors can cause MCU brown-out and other glitches caused by inductive voltage spikes.

Comment: is it too late to pick a microcontroller that has an encoder input?

Comment: @SystemTheory No I am using isolated supply and optocoupler for interfacing I/O

Comment: @Jasen Yes, I know that I need to replace but I want to do it in next version

Comment: You need a faster reader or a lower resolution encoder. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @user_1818839 Can you suggest any solution or IC for fast reading

Comment: Build one in TTL if you want to go retro; write one for a small FPGA (my choice) or buy a chip for the purpose. They're not complicated. This is not the place for buying recommendations.

Comment: @user274774, Thanks for the datasheets.  So mcu is Cortex M3, motor speed around 4k rpm, optical encoder transmissive LED and photo transistor.  All looks good.  I don't think speed is a problem.  Of course there are many possibilities.  One cause is that your interrupt service routine (ISR) is too long/slow, therefore missing interrupts.  In short, it is a software problem/bug.

Comment: @tlfong01The proof would be in seeing some scope traces.  Without that, one doesn't know for sure if it's just a code issue, or a potential electrical interface design issue.

Comment: @user274774 Just dropped in, now. Looking at the datasheets (sie sehen nett aus) and 24 V (I can't tell which encoder you are using, yet), it looks as though the motor can hit 75 rps, though a little less in normal operation. Without the encoder chosen, there's an order of magnitude variation in pulse rates. (20k to 150k?) That's quite a difference. But I've handled 100k without any difficulties while also performing all other necessary work. A Cortex-M3 should be able to handle things fine, if you are experienced in software design (assuming the analog circuit can track it, which isn't hard.)

Comment: @user274774 I'd assume that if your hardware needs to be changed, it shouldn't be difficult. But the only way to tell will be to scope your signals and show them. If the signals are fine and if either you are not sufficiently experienced or else otherwise prefer to use something external, then all of it handled easily with a dedicated SO8 MCU between your cpu and the encoder. (More software, though, and a new toolchain.) Or an ICE40 16-WLCSP package FPGA (is a BGA okay with you?) Personally, I'd either craft my Cortex-M3 software better or else go add a dedicated MCU.

Comment: @user274774 To explore a better Cortex-M3 software design, perhaps study ***all*** of the peripherals with an eye to a high speed design. I'm not familiar with the M3, but most (not all) MCUs have ***variable*** interrupt latency. Sometimes, the latency can be annoyingly long. Tying A/B inputs into rising edge interrupts has a cost. And you need to carefully examine that cost in light of worst case timing issues. If there's too little margin (or none) then you have to drop that idea and look elsewhere. Use your imagination. A simple external circuit might offload just enough work for you, too.